# How to test an Angular 1.x component that uses Angular Material md-tabs - issue with output/event/callback

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-material

The issue here is that the second `it` test fails in this unit test even though in the real browser that output callback is called just fine.

How can I write a unit test so that I can test that `md-tabs` element using the `md-selected` approach when initialising the component *does* call a correct output callback with the right payload data?

Any help appreciated!

`FAILED TESTS:
  Component: gx-tab-list
    ✖ triggers provided output event when a tab is selected
      Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)
    Expected spy clickSpy to have been called with [ Object({ type: 'DO_SOMETHING1' }) ] but it was never called.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/projects/jlr-guanxi-ui/spec.bundle.js:140015:35 <- webpack:///client/app/components/common/tab-list/tab-list.spec.js:85:33)`

```js
import {findIn} from '../../../../test-helpers';
import TabListItem from '../../../models/tab-list-item'


// Input mocks.
const itemListMock = [
  new TabListItem({
    uid: '1',
    label: 'components.reset',
    extra: TabListItem.inBracketsFormat('1'),
    action: {
      type: 'DO_SOMETHING1',
    }
  }),
  new TabListItem({
    uid: '2',
    label: 'components.reset',
    extra: TabListItem.inBracketsFormat('2'),
    action: {
      type: 'DO_SOMETHING2',
    }
  })
];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

import component from './index';

describe('Component: gx-tab-list', () => {
  let parentScope;
  let element;

  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('ngMaterial-mock');
    angular.mock.module(component, ($provide) => {
      // Provide a translateFilterMock.
      $provide.value('translateFilter', (value) => value);
    })
  });

  // Before running each test, compile the desired element and render its input data.
  beforeEach(inject(($compile, $rootScope) => {
    parentScope = $rootScope.$new();
    parentScope.items = itemListMock;
    parentScope.activeTabIndex = -1;
    parentScope.clickSpy = jasmine.createSpy('clickSpy');
    element = angular.element(`
      <gx-tab-list
        model="items"
        active-tab-index="activeTabIndex"
        on-click="clickSpy(action)"></gx-tab-list>
    `);

    $compile(element)(parentScope);
    parentScope.$digest();
  }));


  it('renders a complete view', () => {
    const tabListLength = element.find('md-tab').length;
    expect(tabListLength).toEqual(2, 'Should render two md-tab items.');

    const labelText = findIn(element, '.js-label').text().trim();
    expect(labelText).toEqual(itemListMock[0].label, 'Should render the label.');

    const extraText = findIn(element, '.js-extra').text().trim();
    expect(extraText).toEqual(itemListMock[0].extra, 'Should render the extra text.');
  });

  
  it('triggers provided output event when a tab is selected', () => {
    parentScope.activeTabIndex = 0;
    parentScope.$digest();
    expect(parentScope.clickSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(itemListMock[0].action);
  });
});
```